# SQL-Server Custom Database Role

Tags: sql-server, role

I have a created custom Database Role called Managers. Added db_owner to this role. I would like to Deny DROP Database to this custom Role. But the DENY Drop DATABASE TO Managers is not working

Any work around ?

Comment: Can you post your exact code?

Comment: Are read/write permissions not sufficient ?

Answer (score 3):

The roles db_owner and sysadmin are special cases and can't be denied anything.  My guess is that db_ddladmin, db_datareader, db_datawriter and execute access will give you everything you want instead of using db_owner.